# Go language use internal structures from C

Tags: c, linux, networking, go, system-calls

I would like to be able, in Go, to translate one host address (let's use 'www.google.be') to a sockaddr structure and then use it from a C code.

Translating the host address to a sockaddr_any structure isn't too hard using the http://github.com/jbenet/go-sockaddr module. My code works and is the following:

```
ipAddr, _ := net.ResolveIPAddr("ip", "www.google.be")
sockAddr := sockaddrnet.IPAddrToSockaddr(ipAddr)
rawSockaddr, socklen, _ := sockaddr.SockaddrToAny(sockAddr)
cStruct := sockaddr.AnyToCAny(rawSockaddr)
C.printPointer(cStruct)
```

But, I'm not able to use this `*sockaddr.C.struct_sockaddr_any` variable: `cStruct`, from my C code (it has incomplete definition, so I can't use any of its fields), which is the following:

```
// #include <stdio.h>
// void printPointer(struct sockaddr_any *p){
//     printf(":: %p :: ", p); 
//     // How to use P as a sockaddr? 
// }
import "C"
```

`sockaddr_any` is defined in the core of the Go language (from https://golang.org/src/syscall/types_linux.go). So, I believe it should be linked by default with my C code. But, it seems not to be true. Does someone know what line could I use to include headers from the go language itself (here the syscall structures).

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use struct sockaddr*:

```
void printPointer(struct sockaddr_any *pp) {
    struct sockaddr *p = pp->addr;
    printf(":: %p :: ", p); 
}
```

since sockaddr_any is defined as:

```
struct sockaddr_any {
   struct sockaddr addr;
   char pad[sizeof(union sockaddr_all) - sizeof(struct sockaddr)];
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, it doesn't seem to work. Go is telling me `cannot use cStruct (type *sockaddr.C.struct_sockaddr_any) as type *C.struct_sockaddr in argument to _Cfunc_printPointer`. I would like to avoid unsafe.Pointer if possible. Do you have another idea to help me? Thank you very much

Comment: Well, then keep the original function signature void printPointer(struct sockaddr_any*), declare struct sockadr_any in four C code as shown and then access .addr.

Comment: In fact this is impossible to use the addr field as sockaddr_any has incomplete type (I'm not able to locate the header); but as typecast works, the problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Laszlo answer, there is a simple solution for my problem. It isn't because the definition of the structure `sockaddr_any` isn't accessible in my context (there's no simple way to access the `addr` field) that we can't cast the pointer. So, I can simply do:

```
// #include <stdio.h>
// void printPointer(struct sockaddr_any *p){
//     struct sockaddr *usable_pointer = (struct sockaddr *) p; 
// }
import "C"
```

Then, I can use `usable_pointer` as any other `sockaddr` variable.

Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome. That was my first idea too, but wanted to avoid a type cast.